# TypeError: unorderable types: Tree() < int() (This runs fine in Python 2)

Tags: python

I ran this Huffman Coding code in python 2 and it works smoothly. However, in python 3, it gives me an error as above. I know that the types are not the same (and hence incomparable) but how should I fix this?

Note that the error specifically points out at `q.put((kiri[0]+kanan[0],node))`, which I believe the issue lies on the comparison made in the priority queue.

Example of input that causes the error:

```
3
1
2
3
```

The first line refers to the number of characters. The next lines show the frequency of the first character, second character and so on.

Note that the code somehow runs if the first line is less than 3. For example:

```
2
1
2
```

works just fine

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
n=list(map(int, input().split()))
n=n[0]
li=[None]*n
for i in range(n):
    inp=list(map(int, input().split()))
    li[i]=inp[0]
char=[None]*n
index=1
for i in range(n):
    char[i]=index
    index+=1
freq=list(zip(li,char))

import queue

class Tree:
    def __init__(self,kanan,kiri):
        self.kanan=kanan
        self.kiri=kiri
    def anak(self):
        return int((self.kanan,self.kiri))


q=queue.PriorityQueue()
for nilai in freq:
    q.put(nilai) 
size=q.qsize()
for i in range(size,1,-1):       
    kanan=q.get()
    kiri=q.get()
    node=Tree(kanan,kiri)
    q.put((kiri[0]+kanan[0],node))
huffmantree=q.get()

def traverse(huffmantree,st,pref):
    if isinstance(huffmantree[1].kanan[1],Tree):
        traverse(huffmantree[1].kanan,st,pref+"0")
    else: st[huffmantree[1].kanan[1]]=pref+"0"
    if isinstance(huffmantree[1].kiri[1],Tree):
        traverse(huffmantree[1].kiri,st,pref+"1")
    else: st[huffmantree[1].kiri[1]]=pref+"1"
    return st

binarystring=traverse(huffmantree,{},"")
for i in freq: print(binarystring[i[1]])
```

Comment: I don't see a less-than symbol anywhere in this code.  Where is the comparison being made?

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh yes sorry I was supposed to be more specific. The error points out at q.put((kiri[0]+kanan[0],node)), so I believe it's the comparison in priority queue

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Your posted code is not minimal: it hangs, awaiting input.  This demonstrates that the code is *not* minimal.

Comment: If your code worked in python2 is only by accident. Surely a nonsensical operation like a comparison between a `Tree` and an `int` is a symptom of a bug, whether you detected it or not.

Comment: @Prune I have just edited it. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: @Bakuriu Do you have any suggestion on how I should fix it? Currently the code somehow still runs for less than 3 characters

Comment: Please note that your code *still* requires manual input.  You should give us this as hard-coded input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that you're pushing different types into your tree nodes.  The second element of your ordered pair (2-tuple) is an integer as long as you have a simple tree.  When you get to a child (grandchild) node, however, you try to use a `Tree` object as the second element.

Sorting into the tree requires a well-defined ordering.  A `Tree` and an `int` have no such ordering.

Very simply, you must decide what the other element should be, and keep that consistent in your data handling.  Here's some basic debugging instrumentation:

```
for nilai in freq:
    print("nilai insert", nilai)
    q.put(nilai) 

size = q.qsize()

for i in range(size,1,-1):       
    kanan = q.get()
    kiri = q.get()
    node = Tree(kanan,kiri)
    new_val = kiri[0] + kanan[0]
    print("1st", new_val)
    print("2nd", node)
    q.put((new_val,node))
```

Execution for your 3-1-2-3 case:

```
$ python3 so.py
3
1
2
3
nilai insert (1, 1)
nilai insert (2, 2)
nilai insert (3, 3)
1st 3
2nd <__main__.Tree object at 0x7efd60c9a160>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 40, in <module>
    q.put((new_val,node))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/queue.py", line 146, in put
    self._put(item)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/queue.py", line 230, in _put
    heappush(self.queue, item)
TypeError: unorderable types: Tree() < int()
```

The critical difference is between upper and lower additions:

```
q.put(nilai)    # Simple pair, such as (1, 1)
```

and

```
q.put((new_val,node))
```

Where the second element is a `Tree`.